# KODI How to create a playlist specifying the start and end time of the video

Tags: kodi

I use KODI - https://kodi.tv/ ultimate entertainment center

Is anybody know how to create a playlist with set the start time and the end time of the video.
Video can be located locally or remotely on the server.
The VLC player resolved this problem through m3u format

```
#EXTVLCOPT:start-time=10.000
#EXTVLCOPT:stop-time=20.000
```

But KODI do not accept this format